# Django and Ajax: how can I implement a form text input with suggestions?

Tags: ajax, django, model-view-controller, django-forms, django-views

When you start typing something in Google search you can see suggested queries below based on what you type. Another example is stackoverflow's Tags line.
Is there a simple Django add-on to do this? If not, are there any examples?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any Django add-on to do this. All you need to do is pick a JS library such as typeahead you want to use https://www.google.com.au/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=YXthVMevNMON8Qfs74HABg#q=javascript+autocomplete.

and then write a Django view to return the data for the auto-completion.